# php RegExp: how to use newline in expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, modifier

For example it works:

```
{<div\s+class=\"article\"><h2(.*)</div>}s
```

If I do this way, I get nothing:

```
{<div\s+class=\"article\">
    <h2(.*)
 </div>}s
```

I suspect that I should use some modifier, but I know which one from here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: And if you insist on using regexes to parse HTML, at least use `.*?` instead of `.*` (unless there is only one `<div>` element on the entire page). Also, `{}` is a poor choice for a regex delimiter. Better use `~` or `#` if you don't want to use `/`.

Comment: add /siU and problem must be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the `/x` modifier:

> **x** (PCRE_EXTENDED)
>
> > If this modifier is set, whitespace data characters in the pattern are totally ignored except when escaped or inside a character class, and characters between an unescaped # outside a character class and the next newline character, inclusive, are also ignored. This is equivalent to Perl's /x modifier, and makes it possible to include comments inside complicated patterns. Note, however, that this applies only to data characters. Whitespace characters may never appear within special character sequences in a pattern, for example within the sequence (?( which introduces a conditional subpattern.

It also allows commenting the pattern, which is extremely useful:

```
{<div\s+class=\"article\">  # many spaces between the div and the attribute
    <h2(.*)                 # don't really care about closing the tag
 </div>}sx
```

Comment: Thx a lot!
unclosing <h2> just for debbuging.
Now it works perfect!